# Excluding quotes while scraping text on a forum site

Tags: web-scraping

I am struggling with excluding quotes on a forum website. I need to scrape message texts some of which include quotations as a reference to an earlier message. Scraping all messages that have quotes means I get the same text on scraped data multiple times. In which case analyzing it becomes difficult. Can anybody help me with bypassing quoted text while scraping?
Here is an example page: https://forum.donanimhaber.com/toyota-touch-2-ve-touch-go-2-kullanici-tecrubeleri-ve-klavuzda-yazmayanlar--88405838
Here is the html code of a message with quotation:

```
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table style="width:100%;"><tbody><tr><td>**<blockquote class="quote"><i>quote:</i><br><br>Orijinalden alıntı:  DBolanci <br>   <br>  Beyler alb&#252;m kapağı ve klas&#246;r listelemeyi bende yapamadım. Mp3leri tek tek d&#252;zenledim en ince ayrıntısına kadar yazdım ama g&#246;stermiyor. Nasıl yapacaz bilgisi olan? Ayrıca ara&#231;ta navigasyon &#246;zelliğini nasıl kazandırabiliriz? servis yazılım i&#231;in &#252;cret istiyor :( <br>  </blockquote>**</td></tr></tbody></table> <br>  aynı soruların cevabını bende bekliyorum. yardımcı olabilecek kimse yokmu?
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                    </span>
```

Comment: You need to provide more details: what programming language are you using for starters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the html structure of the message you can see that it follows this format:

```
<span class="msg">
  <table>
    <table> QUOTED TEXT </table>
    TEXT CONTENT
  </table>
```

All you have to do is select `msg>table` content and do not select `msg>table>table` content. In `xpath` selectors this can be achieved in something like:

```
//span[@class="msg"]/table/tbody/tr/td/text()
```

Comment: Thanks @Granitodsurus for the answer. I am not very good at coding. Therefore I don't exactly know where to use your suggestion.
I tried to do this with Chrome's WebScraper extension. I guess it works on JSON code.
An example code I recently used is like this:
{"_id":"yeni_deneme","startUrl":["https://forum.donanimhaber.com/toyota-corolla-2013-2019-ve-2019-ana-konu-temel-bilgiler-ilk-sayfada--71306647-2"],"selectors":[{"delay":0,"id":"message","multiple":true,"parentSelectors":["_root"],"regex":"","selector":".msg > table","type":"SelectorText"}]}

Comment: Do you think I can do this with WebScraper extension.

Comment: Thanks man! @Granitosaurus
I spent my last five days to learn how to make use of the hint you gave me.
And yes now I am able to do it by using python scrapy! Now I know some coding I guess ;)